# Update mysql rows with calculation

Tags: mysql

```
====================================================================
| name | serial_id | timestamp           | cumulative | difference |
====================================================================
|  X   |    AA01   | 2014-12-16 12:50:01 |    832     |            |
|  Y   |    AB02   | 2014-12-16 12:50:01 |   1526     |            |
|  X   |    AA01   | 2014-12-16 12:51:01 |    835     |      3     |
```

Hi folks, MySQL newbie here at it again,

Some time ago, I build a database like this as a way to keep track of a bunch of systems. These systems have a counter which is a cumulative number.  I would like to retroactively update the MySQL table, and add a column that gives me the difference between these counters, essentially, update the row and add the "3".  Here's the wrinkle, there's no unique ID key in the table, but you could consider serial_id+timestamp a "composite key".  What is the SQL statement that I need in order to update the whole massive table with a such calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement that gets the results is:

```
select t.*,
       (t.cumulative -
        (select t2.cumulative
         from table t2
         where t2.name = t.name
         order by timestamp desc
         limit 1
        )
       ) as diff
from table t;
```

In MySQL, you can put this in an update, using `join`:

```
update table t join
       (select t.*,
               (t.cumulative -
                (select t2.cumulative
                 from table t2
                 where t2.name = t.name
                 order by timestamp desc
                 limit 1
                )
               ) as diff
        from table t
       ) tt
       on t.name = tt.name and t.timestamp = tt.timestamp
    set t.difference = tt.diff
    where tt.diff is not null;
```

Another approach, using variables, is a bit cumbersome but may be faster.  This is tricky, because you cannot initialize the variables in the query, so they are always strings:

```
update table t
    set t.difference = (t.cumulative - 
                        (case when @n = name                                       -- name doesn't change so use previous value
                              then (case when (@p := @prev) = NULL then 0          -- guaranteed to fail
                                         when (@prev := cumulative) = NULL then 0  -- guaranteed to fail
                                         else @p
                                    end)
                              when (@n := name) = NULL then 0                      -- guaranteed to fail
                              else NULL
                         end
                        )
    order by t.name, t.timestamp
```

The variable logic is rather complicated -- getting the previous value is a bit difficult in MySQL because all the logic has to fit into a single statement.  The `case` is being used to handle multiple steps in the logic.

Also, this will work better with an index on `table(name, timestamp)`.